Python groupby rank in two different directions
I have a dataframe, d:
    Position    Operation   Side    Price   Size
9   9   0   1   0.7289  -16
8   8   0   1   0.729   -427
7   7   0   1   0.7291  -267
6   6   0   1   0.7292  -15
5   5   0   1   0.7293  -16
4   4   0   1   0.7294  -16
3   3   0   1   0.7295  -426
2   2   0   1   0.7296  -8
1   1   0   1   0.7297  -14
0   0   0   1   0.7298  -37
10  0   0   0   0.7299  6
11  1   0   0   0.73    34
12  2   0   0   0.7301  7
13  3   0   0   0.7302  9
14  4   0   0   0.7303  16
15  5   0   0   0.7304  15
16  6   0   0   0.7305  429
17  7   0   0   0.7306  16
18  8   0   0   0.7307  265
19  9   0   0   0.7308  18

Using the below for updates to d to recalculate Position:
d['Position'] = d.groupby('Side')['Price'].rank().astype('int').sub(1)
But as the order of the sort is different for each Side grouping, is there a way to sort ascending for one group and descending for another?

Code
I think simple solution is to rank the groups by multiplying their Price by -1, where the ranking order should be reversed.
cond = d['Side'].eq(1) # you can use isin when apply to multiple group
d['rank'] = (
    d['Price']
    .mask(cond, d['Price'].mul(-1))
    .groupby(d['Side']).rank().astype('int').sub(1)
)


I initially had this in mind, the drawback is that it would only work with numeric values. If you want to rank strings, dates, Categorical... this won't generalize.

@mozway It's not like the questioner is asking for a generalized answer that covers all data types, and it's obvious that multiplying by -1 is only possible with numeric data.

Yes but the limitations are not obvious, thus my comment. Remember, we want to answers to help not only the OP but also the future readers ;)

@mozway The simple solution of multiplying by -1 will help future readers, and they'll know that they can't multiply date or categorical data type by -1. :)

Also, multiplying by -1 to determine rank or sort direction is a general solution that is not specific to Pandas, although it is only possible for numeric types. This will be helpful for future readers. :)

You could use groupby.apply to access the group.name:
d['rank'] = (d.groupby('Side')['Price']
              .apply(lambda x: x.rank(ascending=x.name==0).astype('int').sub(1))
              .droplevel(0)
             )

Output:
    Position  Operation  Side   Price  Size  rank
9          9          0     1  0.7289   -16     9
8          8          0     1  0.7290  -427     8
7          7          0     1  0.7291  -267     7
6          6          0     1  0.7292   -15     6
5          5          0     1  0.7293   -16     5
4          4          0     1  0.7294   -16     4
3          3          0     1  0.7295  -426     3
2          2          0     1  0.7296    -8     2
1          1          0     1  0.7297   -14     1
0          0          0     1  0.7298   -37     0
10         0          0     0  0.7299     6     0
11         1          0     0  0.7300    34     1
12         2          0     0  0.7301     7     2
13         3          0     0  0.7302     9     3
14         4          0     0  0.7303    16     4
15         5          0     0  0.7304    15     5
16         6          0     0  0.7305   429     6
17         7          0     0  0.7306    16     7
18         8          0     0  0.7307   265     8
19         9          0     0  0.7308    18     9


Most Efficient :
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Position': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Operation': [0]*20,
    'Side': [1]*10 + [0]*10,
    'Price': [0.7289, 0.729, 0.7291, 0.7292, 0.7293, 0.7294, 0.7295, 0.7296, 0.7297, 0.7298,
              0.7299, 0.73, 0.7301, 0.7302, 0.7303, 0.7304, 0.7305, 0.7306, 0.7307, 0.7308],
    'Size': [-16, -427, -267, -15, -16, -16, -426, -8, -14, -37, 6, 34, 7, 9, 16, 15, 429, 16, 265, 18]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

#Fastest and most efficient
# Add a new 'rank' column with ascending ranking for Side=1 and descending for Side=0
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Side')['Price']\
.transform(lambda x: x.rank(ascending=(x.name == 1)).astype('int').sub(1))

df['rank1'] = df.groupby('Side')['Price']\
.transform(lambda x: x.rank(ascending=(x.name == 0)).astype('int').sub(1))


print(df)

Less Efficient :
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Side')['Price'].transform(lambda x: np.argsort(np.argsort(x.values)))

df['rank1'] = df.groupby('Side')['Price'].transform(lambda x: np.argsort(- np.argsort(x.values)))

Output :
'''
   Position  Operation  Side   Price  Size  rank    rank1
0          9          0     1  0.7289   -16     0      9
1          8          0     1  0.7290  -427     1      8
2          7          0     1  0.7291  -267     2      7
3          6          0     1  0.7292   -15     3      6
4          5          0     1  0.7293   -16     4      5
5          4          0     1  0.7294   -16     5      4
6          3          0     1  0.7295  -426     6      3
7          2          0     1  0.7296    -8     7      2
8          1          0     1  0.7297   -14     8      1
9          0          0     1  0.7298   -37     9      0
10         0          0     0  0.7299     6     0      9
11         1          0     0  0.7300    34     1      8
12         2          0     0  0.7301     7     2      7
13         3          0     0  0.7302     9     3      6
14         4          0     0  0.7303    16     4      5
15         5          0     0  0.7304    15     5      4
16         6          0     0  0.7305   429     6      3
17         7          0     0  0.7306    16     7      2
18         8          0     0  0.7307   265     8      1
19         9          0     0  0.7308    18     9      0

'''

